# Explain 2 pairs of parentheses in expression.Compile()()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Could you please explain what this strange code does?

```
expression.Compile()();
```

Why are there 2 pairs of parentheses here? I didn't find anything in google. The full method is

```
public Validator NotEmpty(Expression<Func<IEnumerable<T>>> expression)
{
    var member = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    string propertyName = member.Member.Name;
    IEnumerable<T> value = expression.Compile()();

    if (value == null || !value.Any())
    {
        ValidationResult.AddError(propertyName, "Shouldn't be empty");
    }
    return this;
}
```

It is used like this:

```
_validator.NotEmpty(() => request.PersonIds);  // request.PersonIds is List<int>
```

This method checks if a collection is empty or null. Everything works fine but I am a little bit confused with that  code. I have never seen using 2 pairs of parentheses before in C#. What does it mean?

Comment: That invokes the compiled `Func<IEnumerable<T>>` expression.

Comment: FYI: the 2nd pair of `()` is shorthand for `.Invoke();` So the line is equivalent to: `expression.Compile().Invoke();`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, you pass list of int into the method as expression tree. This expression produces the value of `IEnumerable<T>` (in this case `IEnumerable<int>`).

To get value of expression you need to compile this expression into a delegate `Func<IEnumerable<T>>` and then invoke the delegate. 
In fact, I can write two separate lines of code instead of the shorter syntax used above:

```
Func<IEnumerable<T>> del = expression.Compile();
IEnumerable<T> value = del();
```

Answer (score 4):

The two brackets () is actually an operator which invokes a method or delegate. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/invocation-operator).

The expression "expression.Compile()" seems to deliver a delegate that can be invoked. The second pair of brackets then invokes this delegate.

You could also rewrite this as:

```
var del = expression.Compile();
del();
```